# Tensorflow can't find logs when logdir is stored in variable

Tags: google-colaboratory, tensorboard, stable-baselines

I don't get it, when logdir is stored in a variable, like below, tensorboard opens and displays:

No dashboards are active for the current data set.

```
logdir = "/content/drive/My Drive/logs/logs11112020"
%tensorboard --logdir logdir
```

if I enter the same path into tensorboard works fine

```
%tensorboard --logdir "/content/drive/My Drive/logs/logs11112020"
```

What am I missing?

I am using google-colaboratory and stable-baselines

Comment: Try `%tensorboard --logdir "$logdir"`.

Comment: That solved it thank you!